# Entity frame work: many to many relationship tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

I have a news entity and I get the news based on their NewsID. Now I defined a new entity , a Group and I want to get the news based on their Group ID. I defined a Group news Table Aslo to relate this to table together.
[image]

in news model I have :

```
public virtual ICollection<GroupNews> RelatedGroupID { get; set; }
```

So I Assumed that I defined the GroupNews table values and I can use it in NewsService.

Now lets look at NewsService :

```
    Expression<Func<News, bool>> constraint = null;

    if (user_id > 0 && project_id > 0)
    {
        constraint = e => (e.CreatorID == user_id && e.RelatedProjectTags.Any(p => p.ProjectID == project_id));
    }
    else if (user_id > 0)
    {
        constraint = e => (e.CreatorID == user_id);
    }
    else if (project_id > 0)
    {
        constraint = e => (e.RelatedProjectTags.Any(p => p.ProjectID == project_id));
    }

    else
    {
        constraint = null;
    }

    IEnumerable<News> result_list = null;

    if (constraint != null)
    {
        result_list = newsRepository.GetMany(constraint).OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedOn).Skip(offset);
    }
    else
    {
        result_list = newsRepository.GetAll().OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedOn).Skip(offset);
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        result_list = result_list.Take(count);
    }

    return result_list.ToList<News>();
}
```

}

I add this line to it in order to define a constraint based on GroupID.

```
    else if (groupId > 0)
    {
        constraint = e => (e.RelatedGroupID.Any(n => n.GroupID == groupId));
    }
```

it seems wrong and gives me this error :

> {"Invalid object name 'dbo.GroupNewsNews'."}

Comment: If you are doing Code First why don't you let EF generate the database for you. No need to manually create/alter database tables.

Comment: Please post you `GroupNews` and `News` classes and your context class.

Comment: Based on your screenshot and the error message, you have your table named `GroupNews`, but EF is trying to find `GroupNewsNews`. You might need to override the table name: `[Table["GroupNews")]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.You does not need GroupNewsID in GroupNews table. You need to drop
    this column and create complex key by GroupID and NewsID. In
    the News entity you need to define property:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }
```

In the default constructor for this entity you need to initialize property(need for lazy load):

```
Groups = new List<Group>();
```

Similar changes for Group entity.

2.In the GroupMap.cs you need to define

```
this.HasMany(t => t.News)
    .WithMany(t => t.Groups)
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("GroupNews");
            m.MapLeftKey("GroupID");
            m.MapRightKey("NewsID");
        });
```

3.Write tests for NewsRepository and GroupRepository.

Comment: but then what would be the primary key of the GroupNews table ?

Comment: The combination of the two foreign keys `GroupID` and `NewsID` will be the primary key.

Comment: when I'm adding a new news how could I add the related groupID and newsID to GroupNews Table ?

Comment: but it doesn't work. each time I add a News the related groupID and NewsId does not added to the GroupNews table